# Iteration in DHTMLX Grid Search

Tags: search, grid, dhtmlx

```
dhxTreeGrid.attachHeader("#text_search,,,");
```

According to [this example](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/grid__searching.html#searchboxintheheader) : If i use attachHeader with text_search, it finds that row. However, it does not have "enter" event. So i can't move to another found row.

For instance; i have QR_CODE and QR_COMMON tables. if i search QR_CO, it finds QR_CODE but can not move to QR_COMMON. How can i implement this?

I have also tried [this](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/grid__filtering.html).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not available to iterate through the searching rows. text_search can only select a nearest row matching the entered mask.